# CSS: last nth child until n % 3 == 0

Tags: css

I have a little grid of elements, with rows being a maximum of 3 elements before wrapping to the next row.

```
[] [] []
[] [] []
[]
```

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="width: 33%" />
  <div style="width: 33%" />
  <div style="width: 33%" />
  <div style="width: 33%" />
  <div style="width: 33%" />
  <div style="width: 33%" />
  <div style="width: 33%" />
</div>
```

(inline styles just used for terseness)

What I want to do is provide a `margin-bottom` to all elements except those in the very last row. I'm not quite sure how to do this as I essentially need to target the last `nth-child` until `n % 3 == 0`, but CSS seemingly doesn't have this capability.

Is there anyway to do what I want here?

Comment: You have an option to give margin-top for all elements except for the first 3 as well :)

Comment: Maybe this is what you looking for [Selecting the last grid row in CSS](https://notestoself.dev/posts/css-select-last-grid-row/)

Comment: @BrunoSdoukos, with the option I said we'll git margin-top for all except for first 3, we don't need to know how many elements are there in any row.

Comment: @CharanKumar Wow, that's... a super obvious solution that I should've though of. Nice! Want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Posted as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Devildude4427: simple alternative solution is, set margin-top for all the elements except for the first 3 elements (which'll be on the first row), in which you don't need to worry of what comes at the end.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so I'm not going to answer your question directly and instead suggest this alternative:</sub>

I'd recommend using `display: grid` instead of `display: flex`, but regardless you ought to use [`row-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-gap) on the parent element, rather than attempting to use `margin` on any of the children:

```css
.parent {
  column-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  /* gap: 1em; - this is a shorthand for column-gap and row-gap */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  row-gap: 1em;
}

.parent > * {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: even flexbox does have the gap property

Comment: Not interested in gaps or grid.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below:

```css
.box {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  
}
.box * {
  flex:0 0 30%;
  margin:5px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

.box *:nth-last-child(1),
.box *:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n + 2),
.box *:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n + 1),
.box *:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Another syntax using `:is()`

```css
.box {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  
}
.box * {
  flex:0 0 30%;
  margin:5px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

.box *:nth-last-child(1),
.box *:nth-last-child(2):is(:nth-child(3n + 1),:nth-child(3n + 2)),
.box *:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```